# Unity Game doesnt show in Android Game Launcher

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know why my Unity Game I made for Android isn´t in the Game Launcher after downloading and installing?

The App is already in Google Play Store.

I already searched in the Internet but couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 1):

if you installed from unity on your machine you need to go into your files and find the apk on your android and install it, unity just places the apk you have to install it from within android.

if you have a filemanager on your phone it makes this easy, just navigate to the apk, and click it and hit install.